# MSSQL stored procedure - Timeout expired

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api, dapper, mirroring

We have a Web Api service for report building. This service uses MS SQL 2008 database as a data source. The data base works as a mirror in readonly mode.
The service and the database are hosted on different computers of a single local net.

There is a stored procedure in the database named TicketSaleByAggregator, that selects report data. Sometimes the procedure throws following exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
```

Then the procedure is throwing this exception again and again until we recompile it:: **ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo] [TicketSaleByAggregator]**.
After the command ALTER PROCEDURE, the procedure runs perfectly even on big data sets, but after about 10-15 hours the error throws again: Timeout expired

The procedure parameters:

```
DECLARE @PeriodFrom DATETIME = '2016-12-30 00:00:00'
DECLARE @PeriodTo DATETIME = '2016-12-30 23:59:59'
DECLARE @Dealers Identities
DECLARE @Branches Identities
DECLARE @SaleChannels Identities
DECLARE @Carriers Identities
INSERT INTO @Dealers (Id) VALUES(10068)
INSERT INTO @Branches(Id) VALUES(1),(2),(3) 
INSERT INTO @SaleChannels(Id)VALUES (7)

exec TicketSaleByAggregator @PeriodFrom, @PeriodTo, @Dealers, @Branches, @SaleChannels, @Carriers
```

If we call the procedure locally (on the machine where it is hosted) in SQL Management Studio, then it executes for 15 seconds
If we call the procedure on the machine where the web api service is hosted, in SQL Management Studio, then it executes for 15-16 seconds
.The Result data contains 82540 records

Code of stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TicketSaleByAggregator]
(
    @PeriodFrom     DATETIME,
    @PeriodTo       DATETIME,
    @Dealers        Identities      READONLY,
    @Branches       Identities      READONLY,
    @SaleChannels   Identities      READONLY,
    @Carriers       Identities      READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN   

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    ;WITH ParentDealer(childId, parentId, BIN)
         AS(
             SELECT d.Id,
                    parentDealer.pId,
                    parentDealer.BIN
             FROM   Dealer AS d
                    JOIN (
                             SELECT d.Id,
                                    parentDealer.Id pId,
                                    parentDealer.BIN
                             FROM   Dealer d
                                    JOIN Dealer parentDealer
                                         ON  parentDealer.Hid = d.Hid.GetAncestor(d.[Hid].[GetLevel]() -1)
                         ) parentDealer
                         ON  d.Id = parentDealer.Id
         ),
         CarrierNames
         AS(
            SELECT c.Name AS CarrierName
            FROM Carrier AS c
            INNER JOIN @Carriers crs ON c.Id = crs.Id
         ),
         Result
         AS(
         SELECT *
         FROM
         (     
            SELECT  t.[ExpressId]                           AS TicketExpressId,
                    o.[OrderCreateDate]                     AS OperationDate,
                    1                                       AS TicketCount,
                    t.[Tariff]                              AS Tariff,
                    6                                       AS OperationTypeId,
                    sc.Name                                 AS SalesChannelName,
                    b.ShortName                             AS BranchName,
                    o.CarrierName,
                    o.PaymentType                           AS PaymentType,

                    --financial dealers
                    uDealer.Surname                         AS FinancialDealerSurname,
                    uDealer.Name                            AS FinancialDealerName,
                    uDealer.Middlename                      AS FinancialDealerPatronymic,
                    d.BIN                                   AS FinancialDealerBin,
                    uparentDealer.Surname                   AS FinancialParentDealerSurname,
                    uparentDealer.Name                      AS FinancialParentDealerName,
                    uparentDealer.Middlename                AS FinancialParentDealerPatronymic,
                    parentDealer.BIN                        AS FinancialParentDealerBin,

                    --place dealers
                    uDealer.Surname                         AS PlaceDealerSurname,
                    uDealer.Name                            AS PlaceDealerName,
                    uDealer.Middlename                      AS PlaceDealerPatronymic,
                    d.BIN                                   AS PlaceDealerBin,
                    uparentDealer.Surname                   AS PlaceParentDealerSurname,
                    uparentDealer.Name                      AS PlaceParentDealerName,
                    uparentDealer.Middlename                AS PlaceParentDealerPatronymic,
                    parentDealer.BIN                        AS PlaceParentDealerBin

            FROM    Ticket                                  AS t                
                    INNER JOIN [Order]                      AS o                ON  o.Id = t.OrderId AND o.OrderCreateDate BETWEEN @PeriodFrom AND @PeriodTo
                    INNER JOIN [Terminal]                   AS ter              ON  t.[TerminalId] = ter.[Id]       
                    LEFT JOIN [TerminalData]                AS td               ON  ter.[Id] = td.[Id]       
                    INNER JOIN [SalePoint]                  AS sp               ON  td.[SalePointId] = sp.[Id]
                    INNER JOIN FinAccStation                AS fas              ON  fas.Id = sp.FinAccStationId
                    INNER JOIN Guo                          AS g                ON  g.Id = fas.GuoId
                    INNER JOIN Department                   AS dep              ON  dep.Id = g.DepartmentId
                    INNER JOIN Dealer                       AS d                ON  d.Id = ter.DealerId
                    INNER JOIN [User]                       AS uDealer          ON  uDealer.Id = d.Id
                    INNER JOIN SalesChannel                 AS sc               ON  sc.Id = d.SalesChannelId AND (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @SaleChannels) AND (d.SalesChannelId IN (SELECT * FROM @saleChannels)) OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @saleChannels)) 
                    INNER JOIN Branch                       AS b                ON  b.Id = dep.BranchId AND (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Branches) AND (b.Id IN (SELECT * FROM @Branches)))
                    INNER JOIN ParentDealer                 AS parentDealer     ON  parentDealer.childId = d.Id AND (parentDealer.parentId IN (SELECT Id FROM @Dealers) OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Dealers))
                    INNER JOIN [User]                       AS uParentDealer    ON  uParentDealer.Id = parentDealer.parentId

            WHERE   t.TicketStatusId IN (3, 6) AND 
                    ((EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @Carriers) AND (o.CarrierName IN (SELECT CarrierName FROM CarrierNames))) OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @Carriers))

            UNION ALL

            SELECT  t.[ExpressId]                           AS TicketExpressId,
                    c.OperationDate                         AS OperationDate,
                    -1                                      AS TicketCount,
                    (-1)*ct.RetTariff                       AS Tariff,
                    3                                       AS OperationTypeId,
                    sc.Name                                 AS SalesChannelName,
                    b.ShortName                             AS BranchName,
                    o.CarrierName,
                    c.PaymentType                           AS PaymentType,

                    --financial dealers
                    uDealer.Surname                         AS DealerSurname,
                    uDealer.Name                            AS DealerName,
                    uDealer.Middlename                      AS DealerPatronymic,
                    d.BIN                                   AS DealerBin,
                    uparentDealer.Surname                   AS ParentDealerSurname,
                    uparentDealer.Name                      AS ParentDealerName,
                    uparentDealer.Middlename                AS ParentDealerPatronymic,
                    parentDealer.BIN                        AS ParentDealerBin,

                    --place dealers
                    uDealer1.Surname                    AS PlaceDealerSurname,
                    uDealer1.Name                       AS PlaceDealerName,
                    uDealer1.Middlename                 AS PlaceDealerPatronymic,
                    d1.BIN                              AS PlaceDealerBin,
                    uparentDealer1.Surname              AS PlaceParentDealerSurname,
                    uparentDealer1.Name                 AS PlaceParentDealerName,
                    uparentDealer1.Middlename           AS PlaceParentDealerPatronymic,
                    parentDealer1.BIN                   AS PlaceParentDealerBin


            FROM    Cancelation AS c
                    INNER JOIN CancelationTicket            AS ct               ON ct.CancelationId = c.Id
                    INNER JOIN Ticket                       AS t                ON t.Id = ct.TicketId 
                    INNER JOIN [Order]                      AS o                ON  o.Id = c.OrderId
                    INNER JOIN Terminal                     AS ter              ON  ter.Id = IIF(o.PaymentType = 1, c.TerminalId, t.TerminalId)
                    INNER JOIN Terminal                     AS ter1             ON  ter1.Id = c.TerminalId
                    LEFT JOIN [TerminalData]                AS td               ON  td.[Id] = ter.Id
                    INNER JOIN [SalePoint]                  AS sp               ON  td.[SalePointId] = sp.[Id]
                    INNER JOIN FinAccStation                AS fas              ON  fas.Id = sp.FinAccStationId
                    INNER JOIN Guo                          AS g                ON  g.Id = fas.GuoId
                    INNER JOIN Department                   AS dep              ON  dep.Id = g.DepartmentId
                    INNER JOIN Dealer                       AS d                ON  d.Id = ter.DealerId
                    INNER JOIN Dealer                       AS d1               ON  d1.Id = ter1.DealerId
                    INNER JOIN [User]                       AS uDealer          ON  uDealer.Id = d.Id
                    INNER JOIN [User]                       AS uDealer1         ON  uDealer1.Id = d1.Id
                    INNER JOIN SalesChannel                 AS sc               ON  sc.Id = d.SalesChannelId AND (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @SaleChannels) AND (d.SalesChannelId IN (SELECT * FROM @saleChannels)) OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @saleChannels)) 
                    INNER JOIN Branch                       AS b                ON  b.Id = dep.BranchId AND (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Branches) AND (b.Id IN (SELECT * FROM @Branches)))
                    INNER JOIN ParentDealer                 AS parentDealer     ON  parentDealer.childId = d.Id AND (parentDealer.parentId IN (SELECT Id FROM @Dealers) OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Dealers))
                    INNER JOIN [User]                       AS uParentDealer    ON  uParentDealer.Id = parentDealer.parentId

                    INNER JOIN ParentDealer                 AS parentDealer1    ON  parentDealer1.childId = d1.Id
                    INNER JOIN [User]                       AS uParentDealer1   ON  uParentDealer1.Id = parentDealer1.parentId

            WHERE   c.OperationDate BETWEEN @PeriodFrom AND @PeriodTo AND 
                    ((EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @Carriers) AND (o.CarrierName IN (SELECT CarrierName FROM CarrierNames))) OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @Carriers)) AND
                    c.ResponseXml.value('(/GtETicket_Response/@Type)[1]','nvarchar(max)') != 'ExpressStatus'
    )T

         )

         SELECT *
         from Result


END
```

**UPDATED:** Code on C# side:

```
public IEnumerable<RegisterTicketsByDealerReportItem> GetRegisterTicketsByDealerReport(DateTime periodFrom, DateTime periodTo, int[] dealerIds, int[] salesChannelIds, int[] branchIds, int[] carrierIds)
            {
                var pars = new DynamicParameters();
                var identityFailureValue = new { Id = 0 }.ToEmptyTable().AsTableValuedParameter("Identities");

                pars.AddDynamicParams(
                    new
                    {
                        PeriodFrom = periodFrom,
                        PeriodTo = periodTo,
                        Dealers = dealerIds.Return(ds => ds.Select(d => new { Id = d }).ToDataTable().AsTableValuedParameter("Identities"), identityFailureValue),
                        Branches = branchIds.Return(br => br.Select(b => new { Id = b }).ToDataTable().AsTableValuedParameter("Identities"), identityFailureValue),
                        SaleChannels = salesChannelIds.Return(scs => scs.Select(sc => new { Id = sc }).ToDataTable().AsTableValuedParameter("Identities"), identityFailureValue),
                        Carriers = carrierIds.Return(scs => scs.Select(sc => new { Id = sc }).ToDataTable().AsTableValuedParameter("Identities"), identityFailureValue)
                    });

                var result = Connection.Query<RegisterTicketsByDealerReportItem>("TicketSaleByAggregator", pars, 
                                                                                 commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, 
                                                                                 commandTimeout: dbConfiguration.SqlLargeTimeoutSeconds);
                Connection.CloseIfNoTransaction();
                return result;

            }
```

Sql connection parametrs:

```
<add key="SqlLargeTimeoutSeconds" value="00:02:00" />
<add name="Readonly" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db_Readonly;Integrated Security=True;" />
```

Comment: mmm I think that the problem is not in your store proc ..but maybe in your c# code ... cause if you call it in your SQL Managment from the same server where is your webapi .. i don't think the prob is on the DB side

Comment: On C# side we are using Dapper.SqlMapper.Query method. As i know this method uses standard ADO.NET adapter, that makes mapping to objects from dataSet. I'l try execute this query without Dapper. Thanks.

Comment: can you post the c# code?

Comment: updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

1- Try to use with(nolock) if it is non sensitive transnational data
2- Stop mirroring and check the speed. mirroring may cause this problem

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir. Yeah I have already tried dirty reading: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; stored procedure executed on mirror